# Add hyperlink inside a textarea in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

I am trying to add a hyperlink (which will open a text file onclick) inside a textarea in JavaFX.
So far I have written the code as below:

```
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
    link.setText("Data Sheet");
    link.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(
                        java.net.URI.create("MY text file"));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
mytxtarea.appendText("Please cleck here "+link);
```

This code is not working. Actually the appendtext is not working.Please help.

Comment: Could you provide more information about `mytxtarea`?  What is it's class type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot place a Hyperlink in a TextArea.

A [TextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html) is for editing text, not displaying Hyperlinks.

*Potential Alternate Solutions*

- [HTMLEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/editor.htm#CHDBEGDD) - if you preload the HTMLEditor with text that contains a Hyperlink, then the HTMLEditor should display the hyperlink OK, though the user won't really be able to edit the Hyperlink as the HTMLEditor doesn't really provide link editing capability.
- [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX) - a third party JavaFX control for editing syntax highlighted text, I don't know if it provides link editing functionality or not.
- [TextFlow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) - inbuilt control which allows read-only display that mixes JavaFX nodes such as text and hyperlinks.
- [WebView with an embedded third party JavaScript based editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) - there is source for many JavaScript based editors available on the web which are capable of inline display and editing of hyperlinks, so you could use one of these editors embedded in a JavaFX WebView component.
- [JavaFX based markdown implementation](https://github.com/eugener/markdown-pad-fx) - I have just linked to one such implementation, there are others available on the web if you google them.

Comment: Actually I want to display some text along with a link which will open a excel file on clicking it. So with out using hyperlink can it be possible inside a text area?

Comment: No, it is not possible inside a TextArea.

Comment: I have same requirement. What is the alternative solution?

Comment: Updated answer to add potential alternate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can't place a Hyperlink in TextArea. But you can overlap it with hyperlinks. For example, in my fxml file I have:

```
  <TextArea fx:id="textArea"/>
  <VBox fx:id="box">
      <children>
      </children>
 </VBox>
```

And in my Controller I add a new hyperlink in the "box" node when I need, besides handling his visibility, like this:

```
            box.getChildren().clear();
            // for each new link you need to add
                Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink(stringLink);
                link.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                        // do something
                    }
                });
                box.getChildren().add(link);
            });
```

And then, according to my workflow, I have:

```
private void setEditMode(final boolean editMode) {
    textArea.setVisible(editMode);
    box.setVisible(!editMode);
}
```

The result is that the hyperlinks will appear "in front of" the text area, as it is overlayed, and then you will probably have what you are expecting.